# How can I convert the php web page in the pdf?

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I have multiple pages which have some bootstrap divs , buttons , etc and some google charts too. I want to make a link or button where user can click and convert the page into pdf for viewing later. I used **jspdf** but it makes pdf with no styling whatsoever and do not show charts either.

I used this function

```
function demoFromHTML() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        // source can be HTML-formatted string, or a reference
        // to an actual DOM element from which the text will be scraped.
        source = $('body')[0];

        // we support special element handlers. Register them with jQuery-style
        // ID selector for either ID or node name. ("#iAmID", "div", "span" etc.)
        // There is no support for any other type of selectors
        // (class, of compound) at this time.
        specialElementHandlers = {
            // element with id of "bypass" - jQuery style selector
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                // true = "handled elsewhere, bypass text extraction"
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };
        // all coords and widths are in jsPDF instance's declared units
        // 'inches' in this case
        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, // HTML string or DOM elem ref.
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, // max width of content on PDF
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                // dispose: object with X, Y of the last line add to the PDF
                //          this allow the insertion of new lines after html
                pdf.save('Test.pdf');
            }, margins);
    }
```

and html

```
<button onclick="demoFromHTML();">PDF</button>
```

Comment: this is not related to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DomPDF`, it supports HTML to PDF conversion with styling and font support.

The resource:

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf